# from PHP to Javascript to enter PHP again and set Sessions

Tags: javascript, php, session

Im trying to fix this issue im having. The problem is that I use this code when someone want to sign in to the admin panel:

```
 <script>
    function myFunction() {
       //alert('you can type now, end with enter');
       $("#test").focus();
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           // alert($("#test").val());

           var email = $("#test").val();

           if(email==''){

 // alert("Error.");
 sweetAlert("Oops...", "Error!", "error");

} else {
$.post("sess.php",{ code1: code},
      function(data) {
     // alert(data);
     // swal(data);
     if((data)=="1") {

      swal("Welcome!", "Please wait!", "success")
     } else {

        sweetAlert("Oops...", "Something went wrong.", "error");

     }
      $('#form')[0].reset(); //To reset form fields
      });

    }



        });
    });

    </script>
```

Sess.php looks like this:

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
?>
<?php
include("ipcheck.php");


$code2=htmlEntities($_POST['code1'], ENT_QUOTES);
$info = explode("-", $code2);
$username = $info[0];
$password = $info[1];

 $_POST = db_escape($_POST);


  $sql = "SELECT id FROM adminusers
         WHERE user='{$username}'
         AND pass='$password'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){





    echo "2";


    exit;
  }

  // Session for user
  $_SESSION['sess_id'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
  $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $username;



// DAtabse going on here.




    echo "1";



  exit;

?>
```

So if the username and password is correct the login is successful and those session is set in sess.php:

```
  $_SESSION['sess_id'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
      $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $username;
```

My problem is, how do I get the sessions that is set for the user thru sess.php back to index.php using javascript so I can set the sessions in index.php not in sess.php?

Answer (score 0):

why to you care to pass the session to javascript ? I mean if you set the session server side on sess.php you have already setted it even in index.php (session exists during the entire ... session :-) ) so when sess.php return that the authentication is correct, your javascript should just move the page to index.php like:

```
window.location.href = 'index.php';
```

in index.php, if you print the session print_r($_SESSION) you should see the values that you have previously set in sess.php

If your $_SESSION is empty in index.php probably you have to start the session before reading $_SESSION using session_start();

Comment: That's great please choose my answer ;-)